# The Peculiar and possibly impossible seating arrangement

Tags: lateral-thinking

Four friends are sitting at a table. The order goes like this, Bob, Sam, Mary, and Tony. Tony is next to Bob with no one in between. How is this possible?

Comment: This puzzle can be easily solved with pretty much every kind of table you can think of

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table is:

> Round

I.e.:

> ```
>      Bob
>       |
> Tony--O--Sam
>       |
>      Mary
> ```

Comment: @MikeQ Thanks, apparently I can't read.